# Tinymce editor enable image upload and media upload

Tags: tinymce

i have installed tinymce editor...
i only can add an image or add a media from copying and pasting some url,i need to enable upload image or media...and not only a link,any help please?
i have used this code for my text area:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    tinyMCE.init({
                            theme : "advanced",
                            mode : "specific_textareas",
                            editor_selector : "page_content",
                            plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",
                            theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
                            theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
                            theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
                            theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,spellchecker,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,blockquote,pagebreak,|,insertfile,insertimage",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
                            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
                            theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
                            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
                    });
                    </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default tinymce does not provide  uploading images or media facility from clients computer to your server. But there is a plugin which is paid will give you all this facility. Here it goes.

http://www.tinymce.com/enterprise/mcimagemanager.php

Comment: man, if i purchase the plugin...can i use it in every tinymce editor?...for example if i have 5 websites..and 5 times installed tinymce editor ?

Comment: yes.. if you are using tinymce on same domain. No matter how many times you init it.

Comment: then you should take the server license